# Preprocessing operator "##"

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

While learning about 'Preprocessor Operators' I found in a book a defination :

`#define  CONCAT(x,y)  x##y`

Calling `CONCAT(a,b)` gives a desired output `ab`. But `CONCAT(a,CONCAT(b,c))` won't gives `abc` instead gives an odd output.

Book explains it by saying that **macro parameters that are preceded or followed by `##` in replacement list aren't expanded at the time of substitution.** So `CONCAT(a,CONCAT(b,c))` expands to `aCONACT(b,c)` which can't be expanded further, since there's no macro named `aCONCAT`. 
Ok I get this but book further mentioned that this problem can be solved by defining a 2nd macro that simply calls 1st one. Example

`#define  CONCAT2(x,y) CONCAT(x,y)`

Writing `CONCAT2(a,CONCAT2(b,c))` now yeilds desired list `abc`.

But how ? I think `CONCAT2(a,CONCAT2 (b,c))` will be replaced by `CONCAT(a,CONCAT2(b,c))` which further expands to `aCONCAT2(b,c)`. Now there is no macro named `aCONCAT2` just like in first case then how comes desired output ?

**This is the proof that `CONCAT2(a,CONCAT2 (b,c))` works fine.**

[image]

[image]
See that compiler won't shows any error. Except a warning which is for using getch( ) function.

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: As these both questions were related to ## operator so I put them together. Should I post another one as different question?

Comment: Yes, ideally move the second question into a new question, leaving just the first one here.

Comment: `it with some examples.` really, the simplest way to learn it is to play with it. Or read about some good tricks, like [this](https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have

```
#define CONCAT(x,y)   x##y
#define CONCAT2(x,y)  CONCAT(x,y)
```

then when the preprocessor sees

```
CONCAT(a,CONCAT(b,c))
```

it knows that the replacement list for CONCAT(x,y) is x##y, so it going to replace **x** with **a** and **y** with **CONCAT(b,c)**. The only question is, will it expand **a** and/or **CONCAT(b,c)** before the replacement? **a** is not a macro so no expansion is possible, and in the replacement list x##y, the y is preceded by ## so no expansion is done on the argument CONCAT(b,c). So the replacement is done without expansion, and the replacement list becomes a##CONCAT(b,c), and then before it checks for more macros, it processes the ## and the replacement list becomes aCONCAT(b,c).

If the preprocessor sees

```
CONCAT2(a,CONCAT2(b,c))
```

it knows that the replacement list for CONCAT2(x,y) is CONCAT(x,y), so it going to replace **x** with **a** and **y** with **CONCAT2(b,c)**. The only question is, will it expand **a** and/or **CONCAT2(b,c)** before the replacement? **a** is not a macro so no expansion is possible, and in the replacement list CONCAT(x,y), the **y** is NOT preceded by # or ##, or followed by a ##, so **CONCAT2(b,c)** is COMPLETELY expanded BEFORE replacement. So **CONCAT2(b,c)** is expanded to CONCAT(b,c), which is expanded to b##c, no further expansion is possible, so the **y** is replaced by b##c. The replacement list x##y becomes a##b##c, and either it becomes ab##c and then abc, or it becomes a##bc and then abc.

If the preprocessor sees

```
CONCAT2(a,CONCAT(b,c))
```

it knows that the replacement list for CONCAT2(x,y) is CONCAT(x,y), so it going to replace **x** with **a** and **y** with **CONCAT(b,c)**. The only question is, will it expand **a** and/or **CONCAT(b,c)** before the replacement? **a** is not a macro so no expansion is possible, and in the replacement list CONCAT(x,y), the **y** is NOT preceded by # or ##, or followed by a ##, so **CONCAT(b,c)** is COMPLETELY expanded BEFORE replacement. So **CONCAT(b,c)** is expanded to b##c, no further expansion is possible, so the **y** is replaced by b##c, the replacement list x##y becomes a##b##c, and either it becomes ab##c and then abc, or it becomes a##bc and then abc.

If the preprocessor sees

```
CONCAT(a,CONCAT2(b,c))
```

it knows that the replacement list for CONCAT(x,y) is x##y, so it going to replace **x** with **a** and **y** with **CONCAT2(b,c)**. The only question is, will it expand **a** and/or **CONCAT2(b,c)** before the replacement? **a** is not a macro so no expansion is possible, and in the replacement list x##y, the y is preceded by ## so no expansion is done on the argument CONCAT2(b,c). So the replacement is done without expansion, and the replacement list becomes a##CONCAT2(b,c), and then before it checks for more macros it processes the ## and the replacement list becomes aCONCAT2(b,c).

You might be thinking that

```
#define CONCAT2(x,y)  CONCAT(x,y)
```

means that

CONCAT2(x,y) should be the same as CONCAT(x, y)

but remember that:

1. The replacement list for CONCAT(x,y) is x##y, and because x is followed by ## and y is preceded by ##, when the preprocessor sees an instance of the CONCAT macro, it will not expand the arguments that correspond to x or y before substitution. However the replacement list for CONCAT2(x,y) is CONCAT(x,y) and neither x nor y in the replacement is preceded by # or ## or followed by ##, so when the preprocessor sees an instance of the CONCAT2 macro, it will expand the any macros in the argmuments COMPLETELY BEFORE replacement.
2. Macro expansion of arguments (if allowed) takes place BEFORE substitution. So in CONCAT2(a,CONCAT(b,c)) the CONCAT(b,c) argument is expanded BEFORE the replacement. So we get CONCAT2(a, b##c) and not CONCAT(a, CONCAT(b,c)).

Comment: Good explanation Stuart Little

Comment: Really...It cleared all my doubts regarding every case. I am very thankful to you.